# как извлечь все id и записать их новый массив из массива вложенного?

Tags: php

Массив

```
$arr = [
    ['id' => '86', 'print' => '1', 'title' => 'Equipment'],
    ['id' => '87', 'print' => '1', 'title' => 'Traffic'],
    ['id' => '88', 'print' => '1', 'title' => 'Traffic'],
    ....
];
```

Нужно получить из него:

```
$ids = ['86','87','88'];
```

Чтобы осталось:

```
$arrNew = [
    ['print' => '1', 'title' => 'Equipment'],
    ['print' => '1', 'title' => 'Traffic'],
    ['print' => '1', 'title' => 'Traffic'],
    ....
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ids = [];
$arrNew = $arr;

foreach ($arrNew as &$item) {
    $ids[] = $item['id'];
    unset($item['id']);
}
```

[foreach | PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.foreach.php) 
[unset | PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.unset.php)